# SQL Delete a whole row

Tags: sql

Let's say I have this table :

```
Name | Age | Gender
Jimmy| 166 | Male
Nicki| 0   | Female
```

Now I want to delete the second row without knowing any values. 
I'm only familiar with this command :

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE [condition];
```

But since I don't want to delete all the records, I have to write something in the condition...

So how do I do it? How do I delete just the second row without knowing any values?

Comment: *How can I tell database engine to delete something without telling it what to delete?*

Comment: Try searching for how to select just the second row; you might have an easier time finding that. From there it should be fairly easy to translate to deletion. Note that it will probably depend on what flavour of SQL you're using - MSSQL? MySQL?

Comment: @Yuck How can I tell database engine to delete the second row?

Comment: What you suggest is impossible to do deterministically. If you do not know any values in the table you cannot obviously specify an ordering, nor can you tell it what to delete and what not to. Or, is there a way you are identifying "the second row" that you are not telling us?

Comment: I don't know the answer but tell us the engine you use (Oracle, SQLServer, MsSQL...), it can be useful

Comment: @Davlog SQL data sets are not ordered. What you see as the second row may not always **be** the second row, unless you're using an explicit `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @lc. He may have an ordering in mind, and it's generally possible to select the nth row somehow. He can get the pk from there, and use that in his delete.

Comment: @Yuck well I didn't know that. Just asking isn't wrong, is it?

Comment: @Michelle Yeah I just realized this and edited my comment to add that question.

Comment: @Davlog Asking is absolutely the right thing to do. I just want to be clear that ordering must be explicit or all bets are off as to what will be removed from your table.

Comment: @Davlog How do you know it's the second row you want to delete?

Comment: @Davlog: So what DB engine are you using?

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from your_table
limit 1, 1
```

will delete the second row if the DB delivers the data  in this order which is not garanteed.

**But you can only delete a *specific* row if there is a condition for it or you have a specific order.**

```
delete from your_table
order by name
limit 1, 1
```

Comment: You're taking his question very literally, at least throw a disclaimer on this.  =)  (Also, this is kind of a MySQL-only solution, isn't it?)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server

```
DECLARE @RowToDelete AS INT
@RowToDelete = 2

WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NAME,AGE,GENDER) AS ROWNUM
    FROM Table
)

DELETE FROM MyCTE
WHERE  ROWNUM = @RowToDelete
```

Make sure you define the Order you like in the OVER clause, in order to delete the correct 2nd row.

**EDIT**

Now you may choose which row to delete...

Comment: To reiterate my above comment - this assume an implicit ordering which is not guaranteed. Although it will definitely remove *row number 2*, how can anyone know with certainty what that row is?

Comment: @Yuck Well, i really agree with you, but the question is how to delete the second row. One may provide the order he likes to ensure the second row of his ordering preferences is deleted.

Comment: Correct. The most important bit of your query is the `OVER(ORDER BY NAME,AGE,GENDER)` which defines the ranking used in your later `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Yuck Maybe with my edit it is now clearer.

Comment: @Yuck - It will certainly delete **a** second row, without specifying anything about that row.

Comment: @jyparask there is no correct answer to a wrong question